# What does a bitwise shift (left or right) do and what is it used for?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I've seen the operators `>>` and `<<` in various code that I've looked at (none of which I actually understood), but I'm just wondering what they actually do and what some practical uses of them are.

If the shifts are like `x * 2` and `x / 2`, what is the real difference from actually using the `*` and `/` operators? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: Googling for "bitwise shift" and looking at the first result (Wikipedia) probably isn't that hard. It also answers all of the above.

Comment: Yes, off-course there should be a performance difference. Please see this [link] (http://www.dotnetperls.com/shift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 53):

Here is [an applet](http://bitwisecmd.com/) where you can exercise some bit-operations, including shifting.

You have a collection of bits, and you move some of them beyond their bounds:

```
1111 1110 << 2
1111 1000
```

It is filled from the right with fresh zeros. :)

```
0001 1111 >> 3
0000 0011
```

Filled from the left. A special case is the leading 1. It often indicates a negative value - depending on the language and datatype. So often it is wanted, that if you shift right, the first bit stays as it is.

```
1100 1100 >> 1
1110 0110
```

And it is conserved over multiple shifts:

```
1100 1100 >> 2
1111 0011
```

If you don't want the first bit to be preserved, you use (in Java, Scala, C++, C as far as I know, and maybe more) a triple-sign-operator:

```
1100 1100 >>> 1
0110 0110
```

There isn't any equivalent in the other direction, because it doesn't make any sense - maybe in your very special context, but not in general.

Mathematically, a left-shift is a *=2, 2 left-shifts is a *=4 and so on. A right-shift is a /= 2 and so on.

Comment: ANSI C defines only the two bitwise shift operators >> and <<.

Comment: @TML: ANSI C isn't the only language which uses bitwise shift operators. C++ uses them too and Java does, doesn't it? I guess there are even more languages. and I don't ses "C" in the headlinen, nor in the text or tags of the question.

Comment: No, the question doesn't; which is why I still upvoted you. But at the time (admittedly, this was almost 4 years ago) I felt it was a valuable comment to add. :)

Comment: Does it go `2` `4` `6` `8` or `2` `4` `8` `16`?

Comment: @JL2210: Don't you have the possibility to try it out? Or to calculate it with pen and paper? Since I wrote *=2, and not +=2, it should be the latter, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think I understand now. I was just wondering because I needed to multiply a pointer by 16.

Answer (score 37):

Left bit shifting to multiply by any power of two and *right* bit shifting to divide by any power of two.

For example, `x = x * 2;` can also be written as `x<<1` or `x = x*8` can be written as `x<<3` (since 2 to the power of 3 is 8). Similarly `x = x / 2;` is `x>>1` and so on.

Answer (score 25):

### Left Shift

`x = x * 2^value` (normal operation)

`x << value`  (bit-wise operation)

---

`x = x * 16` (which is the same as `2^4`)

The left shift equivalent would be `x = x << 4`

### Right Shift

`x = x / 2^value` (normal arithmetic operation)

`x >> value` (bit-wise operation)

---

`x = x / 8`   (which is the same as `2^3`)

The right shift equivalent would be `x = x >> 3`

Answer (score 17):

**Left shift**: It is equal to the product of the value which has to be shifted and 2 raised to the power of *number of bits* to be shifted.

Example:

```
1 << 3
0000 0001  ---> 1
Shift by 1 bit
0000 0010 ----> 2 which is equal to 1*2^1
Shift By 2 bits
0000 0100 ----> 4 which is equal to 1*2^2
Shift by 3 bits
0000 1000 ----> 8 which is equal to 1*2^3
```

**Right shift**: It is equal to quotient of value which has to be shifted by 2 raised to the power of *number of bits* to be shifted.

Example:

```
8 >> 3
0000 1000  ---> 8 which is equal to 8/2^0
Shift by 1 bit
0000 0100 ----> 4 which is equal to 8/2^1
Shift By 2 bits
0000 0010 ----> 2 which is equal to 8/2^2
Shift by 3 bits
0000 0001 ----> 1 which is equal to 8/2^3
```

Answer (score 3):

The bit shift operators are more efficient as compared to the `/` or `*` operators.

In computer architecture, divide(/) or multiply(*) take more than one time unit and register to compute result, while, bit shift operator, is just one one register and one time unit computation.

Comment: Isn't there one-cycle multiplication with modern CPUs?

Answer (score 3):

Left bit shifting to multiply by any power of two.
Right bit shifting to divide by any power of two.

```
x = x << 5; // Left shift
y = y >> 5; // Right shift
```

In C/C++ it can be written as,

```
#include <math.h>

x = x * pow(2, 5);
y = y / pow(2, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some examples:

- Bit operations for example converting to and from [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (which is 6 bits instead of 8)
- doing power of 2 operations (`1 << 4` equal to `2^4` i.e. 16)
- Writing more readable code when working with bits. For example, defining constants using
  `1 << 4` or `1 << 5` is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think performance-wise you might find a difference as bitwise left and right shift operations can be performed with a complexity of o(1) with a huge data set.

For example, calculating the power of 2 ^ n:

```
int value = 1;
while (exponent<n)
    {
       // Print out current power of 2
        value = value *2; // Equivalent machine level left shift bit wise operation
        exponent++;
         }
    }
```

Similar code with a bitwise left shift operation would be like:

```
value = 1 << n;
```

Moreover, performing a bit-wise operation is like exacting a replica of user level mathematical operations (which is the final machine level instructions processed by the microcontroller and processor).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"conio.h"

void main()
{
    int rm, vivek;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter any numbers\t(E.g., 1, 2, 5");
    scanf("%d", &rm); // rm = 5(0101) << 2 (two step add zero's), so the value is 10100
    printf("This left shift value%d=%d", rm, rm<<4);
    printf("This right shift value%d=%d", rm, rm>>2);
    getch();
}
```