# c++: what does this insertion expression do and how does it work when passing as a function argument?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

What's the meaning of `binary(number >> 1)`, and how does it work in the following code? Could somebody explain it to me in detail? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream.h>

void binary(int);

int main() {
    int number = 3;
    cout << number << endl;
    binary(number);
}

void binary(int number) {
    if(number <= 1) {
        cout << number;
        return;
    }
    int remainder = number%2;
    binary(number >> 1);  //How does this work exactly?   
    cout << remainder;
}
```

Comment: You mean `>>` ? It´s a "right shift". And because you called it "insertion expression", don´t confuse it´s purpose with streams stuff like cin/cout. It´s the same symbol, but these stream classes are doing something completely different with their overloaded operators.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6385887/487892

Comment: BTW don't use `%2` to get the low bit, use `&1`.  `%` does the wrong thing for negative numbers.

Comment: @BenVoigt His function returns before then if given a negative number

Comment: You can find out the menaning of basic operators etc. by looking them up. E.g. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). The recursive call is more involved, for that you'd better run your program in a debugger, and step trough it statement by statement. Do not ethat `void main` is non-standard, and that `<iostream.h>` is a pre-standard header (before 1998), not usually available with modern compilers.

Comment: @deviantfan Thank you so much! Yes I misunderstood it as an insertion/extraction operator. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<< and >>` operators are bit-shift operators; they change the value based off of the binary representation of the number; an example will clarify:

```
001010 (10)
```

If we do `<< 1` (left shift 1 bit), then we get:

```
010100 (20)
```

If you noticed, the above is *equivalent* to **multiplying by two**; in fact, shifting left n bits is equivalent to multiplying by 2 to the nth power!

If we do `>> 1` (right shift 1 bit) to the original, we get this:

```
000101 (5)
```

Again, if you look carefully, you'll notice the above is *equivalent* to **dividing by 2!** In fact, the right shift operator is the **inverse operator** of the left shift operator, so right shifting n bits is equivalent to dividing by 2 to the nth power!

Also, `void main()` is just plain wrong, so don't use it. `<iostream.h>` should be replaced by `<iostream>` as the former was used prior to standard ISO C++.