# What does the Python operator ilshift (<<=)?

Tags: python

What does the Python operator ilshift (<<=) and where can I find infos about it?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.ilshift

http://www.pythonlake.com/python/operators/operatorilshift

Found no info about what it does in the documentation.

Comment: Not clear what your question is... It's in the "in place left shift" operator. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you asking what the `<<=` operator does?

Comment: *"where can I find infos about this?"* - in the documentation you've linked to in the question you just wrote?

Comment: what do you mean, "what makes"? It's part of python...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is an BitwiseOperators (Bitwise Right Shift):
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

> All of these operators share something in common -- they are "bitwise"
>   operators. That is, they operate on numbers (normally), but instead of
>   treating that number as if it were a single value, they treat it as if
>   it were a string of bits, written in twos-complement binary.

More infos:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

[What does a bitwise shift (left or right) do and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385792/what-does-a-bitwise-shift-left-or-right-do-and-what-is-it-used-for)